# Implementing a scalable encrypted database model

Tags: php, mongodb

So here's the conundrum. We recently decided to move to mongoDB as our option for handling large amounts of contact data. After we decided this, management implemented a policy that required us to encrypt data. We haven't ported our current contacts from our Postgres database yet as we're trying to do this in a scalable manner.

The issue is, we want to be able to query the database data which is encrypted. If we use mongo, we'll be required to pull the entire set of a client's data, decrypt it, and then apply any filters we want. If we use postgres, we get the built-in encryption/decryption handling but we want to allow users to create their own fields, and we'd prefer not to use functionality that includes adding and deleting columns.

Ideas we've entertained:

1. Incorporate Hadoop and allow it to handle all the data processing (and stick with MongoDB)
2. Grouping data for more targeted queries (i.e. this table holds users 20 < age < 29)

We're open to any possible solutions including other database alternatives (although we'd like to stick with MongoDB).

Comment: I'd go with option three and tell management that they shouldn't get involved with security and let the security team handle it.

Answer (score 0):

What about encrypting the filesystem?

Comment: I don't know why you've been down-voted, this seems to be a reasonable solution.

Comment: Sorry, not very familiar with the filesystem encryption territory. What kind of performance overhead does this create for tables that are seeing regular inserts and queries.

Answer (score 0):

I would override the default serialize/deserialize methods of the serializer and pass in a encryption strategy. As mongo serializer I would Doctrine use ODM ( http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/mongodb_odm ). Never used it though, but got good experiences with Doctrine's ORM :)